# Using DataProvider and TestNG displays error [Utils] [ERROR] [Error] java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: selenium-webdriver, dataprovider, testng-dataprovider

Code from LoginTest()

```
@DataProvider(name = "BookingData")
Object[][] getData() throws IOException {

    File src = new File("F:\\selenium\\bha\\MyFleet\\src\\test\\java\\co\\qa\\testData\\DailyTestData.xls");
    System.out.println("Excel is able to read");
    int rowCaught = ExcelUtils.getRow(src, "Sheet");
    int cellCaught = ExcelUtils.getCol(src, "Sheet", 1);

    Object[][] bookingdata = new Object[rowCaught][cellCaught];

    for (int i = 1; i <= rowCaught; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cellCaught; j++) {
            bookingdata[i][j] = ExcelUtils.getCellData(src, "Sheet", i, j);
        }
    }
    return bookingdata;
```

Using DataProvider and TestNG displays error [Utils] [ERROR] [Error] java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass parameters (equal to number of columns in your xls file) to your @Test methods along with dataprovider name.

eg:

if your xls data looks like this

```
data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 |
```

then your @Test method must look like this:

```
@Test(dataprovider="BookingData")
void testMethod(String dt1, String dt2, String dt3, String dt4) // data type from xls should match with parameters, here 'String' is used just for demo )
{

}
```